# Google Polymer: google-map-search doesn't work

Tags: django, google-maps, search, polymer

```
            <paper-dialog id="post" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
                <div class="find-area">
                    <paper-textarea on-input="find" id="find_textarea" class="find-place-text" label="Find your place" maxlength="250"></paper-textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="map-area">
                    <google-map id="[[map]]"
                                api-key="000000000myapi000000"
                            latitude="[[lat]]"
                            longitude="[[lon]]"
                            fit-to-markers>
                    </google-map>
                    <google-map-search id="google_search"
                                        globalSearch="true"
                                       map="[[map]]"
                                       results="[[results]]">
                    </google-map-search>
                </div>
                <paper-button on-tap="[[upload]]">Accept</paper-button>
                <label>coords:[[ results::lat ]], [[ results::lon ]]</label>
                <label>query:[[ query ]]</label>
                <label>map:[[ map ]]</label>
                <label>results:[[results]]</label>
            </paper-dialog>   
 <script>
             function _showPosition(position) {
            try {
                x.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                x.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            }catch (err){
                alert(err+'; position:'+position)
            }

        }
        function showError(error) {
            alert('error:'+ error)
        }*/
        function _submit(event) {
            Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.submit();
        }
        Polymer({
              is: 'profile-new-post',
                properties: {
                    enable : {
                        type: Boolean,
                        value: true
                    },
                    lat : {
                        value : 37.77493
                    },
                    lon : {
                        value : -122.41942
                    },
                    query : {
                        type : String,
                        value : ""
                    },
                    results : {
                        type : Array
                    },
                    map : {
                        type : Object
                    }
                },
                func : function (e) {
                    this.map = this.$.map;
                    post.open();
                },
                find : function (e) {
                    this.$.google_search.query = this.$.find_textarea.value;
                    this.query = this.$.google_search.query;
                    this.$.google_search.search();
                    this.lat = this.$.google_search.results.latitude;
                    this.lon = this.$.google_search.results.longitude;
                    //alert(this.$.google_search.results.latitude + ';  ' + this.$.google_search.results.longitude)
                },
```

I'm trying to use [[]] brackets because of django use {{}}. Map, results and coords are empty at output lables. It shows map with San Francisco but when i try to print text in input it doesn't want to search. The aren't any errors in console. I've saw tutorial video from google about this, but there was old version of Polymer and many things like {{ $.element.atribute }} inside element head doesn't work (it doesn't know what '$' is). Maybe someone can explain for me what's the biggest difference between  [[ ]] and {{ }}, because i can't understand it from official tutorial?

**Solve:** to solve it, i must put source from inside dialog to new template with property is="dom-bind.

```
        <p><paper-button raisedButton on-tap="upload">Upload</paper-button></p>
        <paper-button id="dialogbutton" on-tap="func">Post</paper-button>
        <paper-dialog id="post" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
            <template is="dom-bind">
                <div class="find-area">
                    <paper-input value="{{ input_query }}" on-input="find" id="find_textarea" class="find-place-text" label="Find your place" maxlength="250"></paper-input>
                </div>
                <div class="map-area">
                    <google-map-search
                            id="google_search"
                            map="{{ map }}"
                            query="{{ input_query }}"
                            results="{{results}}"
                            on-google-map-search-results="searchingComplite">
                      </google-map-search>
                      <google-map
                              map="{{map}}"
                              latitude="{{results[0}.latitude}}"
                              longitude="{{results[0}.longitude}}">
                      </google-map>
                </div>
                <paper-button on-tap="upload">Accept</paper-button>
                <label>coords:{{ lat }}, {{ lon }}</label>
                <label>query:{{ query }}</label>
                <label>map:{{ map }}</label>
                <label>results:{{ results }}</label>
            </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. Yes, the `[[]]` brackets are the problem here because they enforce one-way binding. That means that the `results` from the `google-map-search` can't propagate upwards and the labels are empty. You need to change the results=`[[results]]` to `results={{results}}` to enable two-way binding
2. For declerative event handlers, you don't need any brackets. So this line `<paper-button on-tap="[[upload]]">Accept</paper-button>` should be ?`<paper-button on-tap="upload">Accept</paper-button>`
3. To access sub-properties of an data bound object you need to use dot notation (`.`). This line `<label>coords:[[ results::lat ]], [[ results::lon ]]</label>` should be changed to `<label>coords:[[ results.lat ]], [[ results.lon ]]</label>`
4. I would also change `lat` and `lon` to computed properties which either return default values (alternatively just use attributes on your `google-map` element for that) or the values from your search result.

Comment: Ok, i've changed brackets, but even now it doesn't search. Is find function is correct and can i use method search() in such way? Default coords are showing now

Comment: You should use `on-change` instead of `on-input` for your textarea:  `<paper-textarea on-change="find"></paper-textarea>`
Also put a breakpoint in the `find` function to see if it is called.

Comment: it calls, but there isn't result

Comment: the problem is that `google-map-search.search()` is probably asynchronous, you need to either wait until the search is finished by adding a handler to the `google-map-search-results` event or use computed properties from the results. Also `results` is an array, so you can't do `results.lat`

Comment: on-google-map-search-results="searchingComplite"
and searchingComplite : function(){
                    console.log('searchingComplite');
                }, never calls

Comment: hmm check your console in Chrome Dev Tools if there is an issue and if a network request is issued when you type something into the textarea

Comment: i've used extension for chrome, and it doesn't show any requests when i typing only when map is opening in a dialog. there is only one error "Google Maps API multiple times" but even with it map workes